# Angular2 - Updating a form value for data model for multi-select

Tags: angular

I am using a [multi-select package](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) for my angular project. It allows me to bind to my reactive form model which is working fine.

On init of my component, I am storing the initial value from my model in a variable. I allow the user to enable "edit Mode" on my page which gives them the multi-select drop down.

In the event that they want to back out of any changes that they made (selected/removed), I need to re-set the initial value.

`this.ruleAttributeForm.controls['AttributeValue'].setValue(this.initialValueInput, {emitEvent: true})`

I tried to do something like this, which updates the model and the input box itself, however, when I open the dropdown, the values that were previously selected are still marked at selected even though they don't appear in the input.

`<ng-select formControlName="AttributeValue" [items]="valueOptions" [multiple]="true" bindLabel="Value" placeholder="Select one or more values" class="test"></ng-select>`

The values this input selects comes from `formControlName` and the items to pick from come from `[items]`. The `.setValue` appears to work for the model / input but isn't reseting which items are available to pick from (the ones I selected before I reset the control value are marked as in use).

Is there another way I should be handeling updating my form value or is this a plugin issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/blob/master/src/lib/src/ng-select.types.ts), the each element of the list `valueOptions` passed to the `items` property should conform to the type `NgOption` below,

```
export interface NgOption {
    [name: string]: any;
    selected?: boolean;
    disabled?: boolean;
    label?: string;
    value?: string;
}
```

It has an optional `boolean` `selected` property. So try adding a `selected` property with its corresponding `boolean` value as default to each element of `valueOptions` array and then reset this property as well when you reset the `formControl`'s value.